# changing timestamp in logstash 1.4.1

Tags: timestamp, logstash

I am using logstash 1.4.1 with the following config :

```
input {
    stdin {    
    }
}    
output {
    stdout {}
}
```

When I launch the agent and then type "hello" in the console, I get this:

```
2014-05-30T15:02:24.301 +0000 HOSTNAME hello
```

I would like to add 2 hours to the timestamp (I am a french user), and so get this :

```
2014-05-30T17:02:24.301 +0000 HOSTNAME hello
```

In an older version, I was adding this filter to my config :

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('+02:00')"
    }
}
```

and everything worked well, but I think that since the update to 1.4.1 the filter has no impact.

Is anyone is having the same problem or find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem with this filter in version 1.4.1
Here is my configuration:

```
input {
    stdin {}
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('+02:00')"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
         codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Change the timestamp from :

`"@timestamp" => "2014-06-04T02:23:58.719Z"`

To this:

`"@timestamp" => "2014-06-04T04:24:29.718+02:00"`

**Update:**

You have to add `codec => rubydebug` in your output. Maybe it is logstash output bugs if it don't add `codec => rubydebug`

Comment: Waouw, I just don't understand what happen between the filter I have write on my own which doesn't work and the filter that I copy paste from your post which is working. I am not seeing any difference, do you?

Comment: I found the error. You have to use "codec => rubydebug"  in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking that the stdout codec only impacts data formating and not meaning.

Comment: You are welcomed. If my answer has answer your question, please consider make it as accepted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.5.0, we can change the timestamp by using event.timestamp. Here is my configuration:

```
    ruby {
        code => "event['@timestamp'] = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')"
    }
```